# Javascript Google Earth path editor

Tags: javascript, google-earth-plugin

What I am trying to do is create a embedded javascript application where the google earth plugin is embedded in a webpage with various paths drawn on. Here is an example of what I am trying to achieve.

[image: Example of what I want to achieve]

The catch is that the lines need to be editable, with each joint having a handle where the user can click and drag. I have looked high and low on Googles api documentation and I cannot find anything even close to this. If anyone can point me in the right direction it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want each 'joint' to be a dragable placemark so that when you drag it the line geometry is updated.

For reference check out the Google Earth API Samples - Draggable Placemark:
http://earth-api-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/examples/placemark-dragdrop.html

And possibly James Stafford's polyplot:
http://www.barnabu.co.uk/geapi/polyplot/

Together they should help you achieve what you want.